# Windows Sensor API access from .NET with C#, VS2015 and Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net

How can I access the Windows Sensor API from C#?

Everything I can find is either for C++ or referencing outdated libraries.

I tried using the [Windows API Code Pack](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214204408/http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) from the article [Using the Windows 7 Sensor and Location Platform from C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c16973/Using-the-Windows-7-Sensor-and-Location-Platform-from-C.htm).  It sort of works but randomly generates unhandled win32 exceptions:

[image: vshost32.exe has stopped working]

I have also seen references to a [Sensor and Location .NET Interop Sample Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20100212202508/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SensorsAndLocation/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2359) but can't locate the actual library.

I also don't see anything related to Sensors in Reference Manager COM Type Libraries.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Have the same problem and trying to find a solution.

Comment: Same problem here, but it seems to be related to x64-target. x86 is fine. Looks like the author is aware of the issues but the project can't be maintained any more. Very sad. https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/issues/25

Comment: You can see an even newer fork at: https://github.com/contre/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1